# Sencha Touch 2, CPU usage increasing on each store load from remote proxy

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

So my app starts very fast and starts slowing down on each store load.

Model of the store:

```
Ext.define('SkSe.model.Places',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        fields:['id','name','icon_code','required_stamps', 'active_stamps','description', 'campaign_id', 'user_favorites' , 'live_action_number']
    }

});
```

Store itself looks like this:

```
Ext.define('SkSe.store.Places',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',

config:{

    autoLoad:true,
    autoSync:true, 
    model:'SkSe.model.Places',
    sorters: 'name',
    grouper: {
        groupFn: function (item) {
            return item.get('name')[0];
        }
    }, 
    groupDir: 'DESC',
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'SOMEURL'
    }

}
}
```

);

And the store is emptied and loaded each time a user gets to main view like this:

```
var store2 = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Places');
store2.data.clear();
store2.getProxy().setUrl('someurl');
store2.load();
```

For some reason each time user returns to main view the cpu load increases few percent until it gets painfully slow.

It must be something to do with store loading and clearing because if I remove it the CPU overload doesn't happen.

Also the amount of data that arrives via proxy is negligible.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the records are being destroyed by clearing the store's underlying Collection. I would suggest using the store's [removeAll](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-removeAll) method which will do a destroy on each record and hopefully free up some of the resources used by each.

If your store is dealing with large datasets then this might add up and cause a slowdown.

Comment: Unfortunatly I did try removeAll before and nothing changed.